# How to send & receive msgs using XMPPframework in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I want to send & receive msg using xmppframework in iphone so I am include all files like XMPPframwork , Kissxml and Asyncsocket but I can't send & receive msg so I want this functionality in my iphone apps so please send me code of that or any link which i develop this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [XMPP libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/),Available in **C/C++** and **ObjC** both .Check the [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/) for XMPP framework , you could also [browse](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/browse/) the code for that

Check the SO post.

[How to send message using XMPP Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324779/how-to-send-message-using-xmpp-framework)