# iOS XMPP not able to send message

Tags: ios, xmppframework

i am working on XMPP based ios project. i am tring to send message but i am not able to send message. means receiver will not receive the message.
here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)sendMessageNow:(id)sender
{

 NSString *messageStr =messageField.text;

if([messageStr length] > 0)
{
    NSLog(@"Message sending fron Gmail");
    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:messageStr];
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"destination address"];
    [message addChild:body];
    NSLog(@"message1%@",message);

    [[self appDelegate].xmppStream sendElement:message];
}

  NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
//[self sendMessage];

if ([self.messageField.text length]>0) {

    if (isfromMe)
    {
        NSString *rowNum=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)sphBubbledata.count];
        [self adddMediaBubbledata:kTextByme mediaPath:self.messageField.text mtime:[formatter stringFromDate:date] thumb:@"" downloadstatus:@"" sendingStatus:kSending msg_ID:[self genRandStringLength:7]];
        [self performSelector:@selector(messageSent:) withObject:rowNum afterDelay:1];

        isfromMe=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [self adddMediaBubbledata:kTextByOther mediaPath:self.messageField.text mtime:[formatter stringFromDate:date] thumb:@"" downloadstatus:@"" sendingStatus:kSent msg_ID:[self genRandStringLength:7]];
        isfromMe=YES;
    }
    self.messageField.text=@"";
    [self.chattable reloadData];
    [self scrollTableview];
  }
  }
```

and here is my senderdidreceivemessage method from appdelegate.m

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
 {
   DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);


 [[self xmppStream] sendElement:message];

        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.alertAction = @"OK";
   localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
  //  localNotification.alertBody = xmppmessage;
 localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];




   // A simple example of inbound message handling.

if ([message isChatMessageWithBody])
 {
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [xmppRosterStorage userForJID:[message from]
                                                             xmppStream:xmppStream
                                                   managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext_roster]];

    NSString *body = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    NSString *displayName = [user displayName];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:displayName
                                                            message:body
                                                            delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        // We are not active, so use a local notification instead
          UILocalNotification *localNotification =     [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"Ok";
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From: %@\n\n%@",displayName,body];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  static NSString *L_CellIdentifier = @"SPHTextBubbleCell";
  static NSString *R_CellIdentifier = @"SPHMediaBubbleCell";



   SPH_PARAM_List *feed_data=[[SPH_PARAM_List alloc]init];
   feed_data=[sphBubbledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   if ([feed_data.chat_media_type isEqualToString:kTextByme]||[feed_data.chat_media_type isEqualToString:kTextByOther])
   {
     SPHTextBubbleCell *cell = (SPHTextBubbleCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:L_CellIdentifier];
      if (cell == nil)
     {
        cell = [[SPHTextBubbleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:L_CellIdentifier];
    }
    XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *user = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //cell.textLabel.text = user.displayName;
    //[self configurePhotoForCell:cell user:user];


    cell.bubbletype=([feed_data.chat_media_type isEqualToString:kTextByme])?@"LEFT":@"RIGHT";
    cell.textLabel.text = user.displayName;
    cell.textLabel.tag=indexPath.row;

    cell.timestampLabel.text =  @"02:20 AM";
    cell.CustomDelegate=self;
    cell.AvatarImageView.image=([feed_data.chat_media_type isEqualToString:kTextByme])?[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePic"]:[UIImage imageNamed:@"person"];
  //  cell.AvatarImageView.image=[
    [self configurePhotoForCell:cell user:user] ;
    return cell;

   }



 SPHMediaBubbleCell *cell = (SPHMediaBubbleCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:R_CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
 {
    cell = [[SPHMediaBubbleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:R_CellIdentifier];
 }
cell.bubbletype=([feed_data.chat_media_type isEqualToString:kImagebyme])?@"LEFT":@"RIGHT";
cell.textLabel.text = feed_data.chat_message;
cell.messageImageView.tag=indexPath.row;
cell.CustomDelegate=self;
cell.timestampLabel.text = @"02:20 AM";
cell.AvatarImageView.image=([feed_data.chat_media_type isEqualToString:kImagebyme])?[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePic"]:[UIImage imageNamed:@"person"];

return cell;
}
```

and configure photo method

```
- (void)configurePhotoForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell user:(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject *)user
 {
// Our xmppRosterStorage will cache photos as they arrive from the xmppvCardAvatarModule.
// We only need to ask the avatar module for a photo, if the roster doesn't have it.

if (user.photo != nil)
{
    cell.imageView.image = user.photo;
}
else
{
    NSData *photoData = [[[self appDelegate] xmppvCardAvatarModule] photoDataForJID:user.jid];

    if (photoData != nil)
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
    else
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"user2"];
  }
 }
```

**EDIT**

Both are send by me but it looks in same window, when i click on one time send button it looks in sender message and second time looks in receiver message. and receiver will not receive message.

[image: Error]

**EDIT**

Here is response after i click on send button.

> function:-[ChathistryViewController sendMessageNow:] line:414 content:Message sending fron Gmail
>   function:-[ChathistryViewController sendMessageNow:] line:421 content:message1ghfhxfghh
>   2015-06-12 13:03:22:071 projectname[7556:2f03] SEND: ghfhxfghh
>   2015-06-12 13:03:22:389 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: ghfhxfghh
>   2015-06-12 13:03:22:390 CloseChat[7556:2f03] SEND: ghfhxfghh
>   2015-06-12 13:03:22.393 projectname[7556:49110] Attempting to schedule a local notification {fire date = (null), time zone = (null), repeat interval = 0, repeat count = UILocalNotificationInfiniteRepeatCount, next fire date = Friday, June 12, 2015 at 1:03:22 PM India Standard Time, user info = (null)} with a sound but haven't received permission from the user to play sounds
>   2015-06-12 13:03:22:697 CloseChat[7556:7347] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:23:004 projectname[7556:7347] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:23:004 projectname[7556:7347] SEND: http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='jwchat.org'>
>   2015-06-12 13:03:23:619 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:23:619 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:23:619 CloseChat[7556:7347] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:23:925 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:23:926 projectname[7556:7347] SEND: http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='jwchat.org'>
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:063 projectname[7556:7627] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:064 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: PLAINDIGEST-MD5SCRAM-SHA-1
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:065 CloseChat[7556:607] SEND: biwsbj1jaGlyYWcscj1EMjUxMEQ2NC05MzZFLTQxMkUtQjY1Ri0zM0VFQjE1ODcxRjc=
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:306 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: cj1EMjUxMEQ2NC05MzZFLTQxMkUtQjY1Ri0zM0VFQjE1ODcxRjdXVnB5eEp3b2lCRC9rUThvRkdhbGdRPT0scz1DZVZpSFFXNW9XRDVVNU90WUNMWExnPT0saT00MDk2
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:321 projectname[7556:7347] SEND: Yz1iaXdzLHI9RDI1MTBENjQtOTM2RS00MTJFLUI2NUYtMzNFRUIxNTg3MUY3V1ZweXhKd29pQkQva1E4b0ZHYWxnUT09LHA9TWlsaW5TczI4b2VBd1dtQ3pWY21TWXZQWEFnPQ==
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:562 projectname[7556:7627] RECV: dj1WeVdSaWRTTHVxYzhkV0E2aEg3OW9mU0FpYmc9
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:562 projectname[7556:7627] SEND: http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' to='jwchat.org'>
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:871 projectname[7556:7627] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:871 projectname[7556:7627] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:25:872 projectname[7556:7627] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:178 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: chirag@jwchat.org/341204969114349440629043
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:179 projectname[7556:7347] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:485 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:486 projectname[7556:7627] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:487 projectname[7556:7347] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:488 projectname[7556:7627] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:714 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:946 projectname[7556:7347] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:947 projectname[7556:6e13] SEND: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:26:948 projectname[7556:6e13] RECV: 
>   2015-06-12 13:03:27:180 projectname[7556:7627] RECV:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must make sure first that your XMMP client is set up correctly. Then make sure that you are sending the message, and that you have the right sender.

*For those who will now say that this is a comment, not an answer, I don't have enough reputation to comment!*

Comment: ok. thanks for replay. i want to send message on jabber client. and currently i am using jabber server in my app.

Comment: https://github.com/wufulin/xmppClient maybe this can help you. But it is very straight forward for using, so your mistake must be in the server setup or the receiver. Or you can share the error you get while trying to send the message.

Comment: i am not getting any error but i am receving and sending message in same window. which is sent.

Comment: that means the receiver is wrong, you are sending the message to yourself?

Comment: I am using this as my design view for send and receive message. https://github.com/sibahota059/FlatChatBubble

Comment: [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"destination address"]; 

destination address should be the receiver.
have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324779/how-to-send-message-using-xmpp-framework

Comment: sorry but i can't understand. how to recognize receiver's address ?

Comment: Well if you can send messages to you, that means your jabber is working, now you should setup the XMPP chat server, and every user should register on that server and will become an ID, that ID would be the receiver's address.

Comment: thanks for your replay. have you any sample app from which i can understand ?

Comment: This link can be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850619/build-a-chat-application-in-ios-using-xmpp

Comment: You are welcome. If you think you need more help with the iOS part,feel free to contact me per email, i have an IOS app with XMPP implemented.

Comment: Thanks . please check your mailbox.

Comment: i have tried this and with setting breakpoint i found that with click on login button i am not able to enter in `if([messageStr length] > 0)` condition. and it pass the value of textfield as `nil`. do you have any idea why this happen?

Comment: yes, your messageStr is empty.

NSString *messageStr = @"you should add your message here";

Comment: i am trying on it and give you replay.

Comment: I have tried and i forgot to write `self` before `messagefield` so, now i am able to enter in if condition. but still message is not sent to receiver. and it comes in samewindow. i thing somefolt in `uitableview datasource` method. i edited code above for `cell for row at indexpath`

Answer (score 1):

The Control is just for UI purpose, I never wrote any code to send or receive a message from the server because I m not sure whether a user will use any third party SDK or XMPP or normal REST API.

So, you make the Server part & UI part separately.

Your question :
 Both are sent by me but it looks in the same window when I click on one-time send button it looks in sender message and second time looks in receiver message. and receiver will not receive a message.

Ans: Yes, I have done that for Demo purpose, based on the response you will get from server you have to make the changes in code.

How to use: 
1. Declare an NsmutableArray & initialize it on viewdidload.
2. When you send an Message, image, create a Bubbledata & add it to the array & then reload the Tableview.

```
 [self adddMediaBubbledata:kTextByme mediaPath:@"Hi, check this new control!" 
mtime:@"8:30 AM" thumb:@"NA"  downloadstatus:@"" sendingStatus:kSent  msg_ID:@"AB4353GH"];
```

Use Below types for send and receive:

```
 kTextByme: if you sending a text
 kImageByme : if you are sending an Image
 kTextByOther : if you receiving an Text
 kImageByOther : if you are receiving an Image
```

Now update the send Status

```
    kSent      : you successfully sent an message
    kFailed    : message sendig failed
    kSending : your message is sending to server
```

So , based on the above information , make the changes and let me know if you require any other help

Answer (score 0):

Please locate below delegate in XMPP Client(XMMPFramework), it will handle the received instant messages to you.

// XMPP Delegate method: xmpp client receives a message

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{

  // some computation stuff

  return ;

}
```